# How many work hours for 280Slides?

Tags: objective-j, sproutcore

Here's an interesting question for J-Objective coders out there. How many work hours would it take for you to code the clone of 280Slides.com with Sproutcore. Also estimates with Cappuccino are ok because they are pretty same kind of frameworks, at least to my eye.

Not that I'm planning to do it but 280Slides has all the basic functions for an average program and it's easy & simple & free to check out if you haven't tried it out yet. I'm trying to find out because a part of my next freelance project is to develop a private software for a company and it has a lot of similar features like shapes and image uploading, just like 280Slides. I'm going to outsource J-Objective coding so I'm very interested to hear what's the real time it takes to code something like that so I don't get ripped off. I don't have nothing against paying a great salary for a good job but so many outsource companies are ripping buyers off because they don't know how long it really takes as man hours. My buddy actually paid $60 a hour for this one feature program he outsourced.

Thanks for everybody who takes time to answer, gotta love stackoverflow for getting all the experts answering questions :)

Comment: Sproutcore is JavaScript. Objective-J is specific to Cappucino.
Have you tried asking the 280Slides authors?
$60/hour is a reasonable rate for contract programming work performed by someone in a developed nation.

Answer (score 1):

The Authors said, it took "4 month" to build 280Slides, I cannot remember where they said that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the exact posibilities of Objective-J and Cappuccino - I am a .NET/C# developer - and seeing 280Slides.com for the first time, I would make a first estimate in the range of 500 to 1000 man hours, probably (much) closer to 1000 then to 500.